# How to get the NDSolve to seek only a real solution?

Tags: differential-equations

I use `NDSolve` to solve system of 2 ODE of 1st order:

```
J[G_, V_: 1] := 
  Piecewise[{{2 (-G \[Pi] - Sqrt[G (-G + 2 V)] + 
        G ArcCos[-1 + G/V]),   0 < G < 2 V && Abs@Im[G] < 10^-12}}, 0];
eqs = {-Derivative[1][B][x] == 2 J[G[x]], 
   Derivative[1][G][x] == B[x], B[x0] == (2 V*x0^3)/9, 
   G[x0] == (V*x0^4)/18} /. {V -> 1, x0 -> 0.1}
s2 = First@NDSolve[eqs, {B, G}, {x, 0, 4}]
Plot[{B[x], G[x]} /. s2 // Evaluate, {x, 0, 4}
 , PlotRange -> All
 , PlotLegends -> {B, G}]
```

RHS of 2nd equation (function `J[G]`) has a jump at the point `G = 2`. As I concluded from reading this website, that is why the NDSolve gives a complex solution for `G> 2` (`x` larger than approximately `2.4`), although the correct solution must be real on the entire `x` axis:

```
{B[x], G[x]} /. s2 /. {x -> 2.5}
```

Note that

```
Piecewise[{{2 (-G \[Pi] - Sqrt[G (-G + 2 V)] + G ArcCos[-1 + G/V]),   
   0 < G < 2 V}, 0]
```

gives strange (non-evaluated) result when G is complex. This is why I added condition `Abs@Im[G] < 10^-12` to definition of function `J[G]`, but it did not help.

I expect that for `G>0` solution for `B[x]` 1st equation should be `B'[x]==0` and hence `B==const`, but `NDSolve` gives wrong complex function.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You define `J[]`, but use `J2[]` in your ODEs. Speaking of which, are you aware that `NDSolve[]` can directly deal with second-order ODEs? `NDSolve[{G''[x] == -2 J2[G[x]], (* stuff *)}, (* stuff *)]`

Comment: I corrected J2 to J.

Comment: Try this: `J[G_, V_: 1] := Piecewise[{{2 (G ArcCos[G/V - 1] - G π - Sqrt[G (2 V - G)]), 0 < Re[G] < 2 V}}, 0]; With[{V = 1, x0 = 1/10}, gg = NDSolveValue[{G''[x] == -2 J[G[x]], G[x0] == (V x0^4)/18, G'[x0] == (2 V x0^3)/9}, G, {x, 0, 4}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]]; Plot[{Re[gg[x]], Re[gg'[x]]}, {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: This seems to work. Please write your solution as answer so I could accept it,